# Get embedded UITableView from container?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am working with a library from github which requires a table view to be within a view controller.

Like this: `HidingNavigationBarManager(viewController: self, scrollView: tableView)`

But my table view is not inside my VC, instead I have a container view with an embedded segue to the table view.

So how can I pass my embedded table view thats inside my container view in the function:

```
HidingNavigationBarManager(viewController: self, scrollView: tableView)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a ViewController has containerViews in it, it triggers `prepareForSegue` Method in a ViewController that contains containerViews after viewDidLoad. There you can get reference of viewController which is embedded in a containerView.

So for example you have a containerView which is linked with viewcontroller of class TestViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   var vc: AnyObject = segue.destinationViewController
    if vc .isKindOfClass(TestViewController) {
        NSLog("GOTCHA!")
    }
}
```

So you can refer to the tableView in a TestViewController like forexample: `vc.tableView` inside the `if` block of prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Is there then anyway that I can call vc.tableView from viewDidLoad?

Comment: I don't think so haven't tried. But I think you can achieve what you are trying to do in viewdidappear as well.

Comment: Wow I've been searching for this for weeks now. How come this is nowhere else on the internet? Thank you.